# Debugging a marionette application

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm very new to Backbone and Marionette and RequireJS. I am supporting an existing application that uses these frameworks. The app is huge. Where should I start looking? I want to learn which file gets loaded first, kinda like the entry point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are at least 2 options here. First - try to find Application object creation somewhere in your code `Marionette.Application()`. Essentially - if it's created, it's done at the very beginning. More info here: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md

On the other hand - check whether you app follows a pattern. It's common to start evey page using the same approach (load setting, intialize base views, etc) - maybe there is one entry point somewhere in the main directory which is executed every time.

Ofen application among different part of application is done via Radio channels. Try to find `Radio.channel` in your code - it should be executed at the beginning as well

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll do that! :)